# complex numbers (Proving an equality)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let : $$ \bbox[,5px]
{ (\forall z\in \mathbb{C}): A(z)=z^2+2z+2 } $$

Prove that : $$ \bbox[pink,5px]
{ (\forall z\in \mathbb{C}) ; (A(z)=A(\bar{z})) \Leftrightarrow (z=\bar{z} \text{ $$ or   $$  } \Re(z)=-1) } $$

I tried to solve the problem by considering $$ \bbox[,px]  (A(z)=A(\bar{z})) $$;  letting z=x+iy but I am stuck, can someone please provide a hint ? am I even on the right track ?

I couldn't find any error in my calculation. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is A(z)? Arg(z)

Comment: Hint: $\,A(z)=A(\bar z) \iff z^2 - \bar z^2 + 2(z - \bar z) = 0\,$. Now factor the difference of squares and $\ldots$

Comment: @gimusi , I've already identified A(z) as :  $$ \bbox[,5px]
{ (\forall z\in \mathbb{C}): A(z)=z^2+2z+2 } $$

Comment: @dxiv Thanks ,I guess I shouldn't have considered z=x+iy at first ,

Comment: @redaahcirt You can work it out that way, too, but the calculations are somewhat more tedious, and unnecessarily so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$A(z)=z^2+2z+2 \quad A(\bar z)=\bar z^2+2\bar z+2$$

then

$$A(z)=A(\bar z) \iff z^2+2z+2= \bar z^2+2\bar z+2 \iff z^2+2z= \bar z^2+2\bar z\\\iff z^2-\bar z^2 = 2\bar z -2z \iff (z-\bar z)(z+\bar z) = -2(z-\bar z)\iff\\ z=\bar z\quad \lor\quad z+\bar z=2\cdot\Re(z)=-2$$

Comment: This is helpful thank you

Comment: @redaahcirt It was not so difficult to derive. I suggest always to try to solve this kind of problem directly by algebraic manipulation, usually it is not necessary put z into the form $x+iy$.